# How can I convert this json data to html table with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I want to create an `HTML` table using `json` data. The `json` data will change over time. When convert this `json` data to an `HTML` table, the table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R2dW.png) with consistent. It means the alignment of values and the width of the table. How can I convert the `json` data into an `HTML` table?

```
[

    {
        "1": [{
            "Time": "01:35 AM",
            "Location": "dhaka bangladesh",
            "BUS Detail": {
                "air_Logo": "logo goes here",
                "air_Name": "Airbus"
            },
            "busNo": "AK119",
            "arrTime": "05:40 AM",
            "arrival Loc": "barisal"
        }]
    }

]`// Extract value from table header. 

let col = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
    for (let key in myBooks[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            col.push(key);


        }
    }
}
// Create a table.
const table = document.createElement("table");

// Create table header row using the extracted headers above.
let tr = table.insertRow(-1); // table row.

for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    let th = document.createElement("th"); // table header.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
}

// add json data to the table as rows.
for (let i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        const tabcel = tr.insertCell(-1);
        if (typeof myBooks[i][col[j]] === 'object') {


                tabcel.setAttribute('rowspan','2');
                tabcel.innerHTML = `<table><td>${myBooks[i][col[j]].air_Name}</td> <td> ${myBooks[i][col[j]].air_Logo}</td> </table>`;

        } else {
            tabcel.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
        }

    }



    // for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
    //     let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
    //     tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
    // }
}

// Now, add the newly created table with json data, to a container.
const divShowData = document.getElementById('showData');
divShowData.innerHTML = "";
divShowData.appendChild(table);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your object is not flat, you cannot truly render it all to table. You have to make a decision about the nested objects. Below I am simply using json.stringify to show those objects in a table cell. You should of course handle this according to your needs.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "1": [
      {
        Time: "01:35 AM",
        Location: "dhaka bangladesh",
        "BUS Detail": {
          air_Logo: "logo goes here",
          air_Name: "Airbus"
        },
        busNo: "AK119",
        arrTime: "05:40 AM",
        "arrival Loc": "barisal"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const base = data[0]["1"];

const table = document.createElement("table");
const thead = table.createTHead();
const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.append(tbody)

const headRow = thead.insertRow();
const headers = Object.keys(base[0]).forEach((head) => {
  let cell = headRow.insertCell();
  cell.textContent = head;
});

base.forEach((obj) => {
  const row = tbody.insertRow();
  const vals = Object.values(obj);
  vals.forEach((v) => {
    const cell = row.insertCell();
    if (typeof(v) !== 'string') {
      return cell.textContent = JSON.stringify(v);
    }
    cell.textContent = v
  });
});

document.body.append(table)
```